# How to see the hearts in minecraft realms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would to know how to configure the minecraft realms to see the live about all members in game, because when i use tab i only see the status connection, like this...
[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Realms. Generally almost nothing that happens after you actually join the world is any different to a regular server or even Singleplayer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want information about players in the tab menu, you need scoreboards. Minecraft has some simple commands to do this, but you need operator permissions.

`/scoreboard objectives add Hearts health` will create an objective called "Hearts" based on the amount of health a player has.

`/scoreboard objectives setdisplay list Hearts` will display the objective "Hearts" on the tab menu, resulting in:
[image]

Past a certain point, this will turn into a number value, but that will only happen at around 20/25 hearts, which is unlikely in standard gameplay.

Note: This may appear as 0 until a player's health changes for the first time - afterwards it will operate normally.

You can read up further at [the wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it that all i need.